# ExpressJS Routes + Websockets - Share Port

Tags: node.js, express, https, websocket, port

I have an https expressjs server with websockets (using the 'ws' package). As far as I understand sockets and ports, I should be able to add a route alongside the websocket connections. The main use-case is so that the server can be curled (none of the ws curl requests I've seen online worked.)

Unfortunately I only have 1 port to use for the server and websockets. How can I set this up so that **app** and **server** can both listen on the same port?

I've seen a few comments on SO that indicates that it can be done, but no code examples, or it's for very different packages.

I'm using the 'ws' package: https://www.npmjs.com/package/ws

```
const port = 8888;
const http = require('http');
const https = require('https');
const express = require('express');
const websocket = require('ws');
const app = express();
      app.use( express.static('public') );
      app.get('/curl', (req, res) => res.send('Hello World')).listen( port );

const httpsServer = https.createServer( credentials, app );
const wss = new websocket.Server({ server: httpsServer });

httpsServer.listen( port, function listening(){
    console.log( 'listening on ' + port );
});
```

Currently I get the "EADDRINUSE" error since I'm using the same port for two 'servers'.

> FOLLOW-UP

- Express app doesn't need to also listen if another server is.
- To curl https, you have to provide the cert details, or use the '-k' (insecure) method.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your code shows you trying to start two servers on the same port.

This line creates a new http server and attempts to start it on port 8888:

```
app.get('/curl', (req, res) => res.send('Hello World')).listen( port );
```

These lines create a new https server and attempt to start it on port 8888 also.

```
const httpsServer = https.createServer( credentials, app );

httpsServer.listen( port, function listening(){
    console.log( 'listening on ' + port );
});
```

You cannot do that.  If you just want one https server that works for both your web requests and your webSocket (a common way to do things), then change your code to this:

```
const port = 8888;
const https = require('https');
const express = require('express');
const websocket = require('ws');
const app = express();

app.use( express.static('public') );
app.get('/curl', (req, res) => res.send('Hello World'));

const httpsServer = https.createServer( credentials, app );
const wss = new websocket.Server({ server: httpsServer });

httpsServer.listen( port, function listening(){
    console.log( 'listening on ' + port );
});
```

which just removes the `.listen(port)` that operates on the `app` object because that will create an http server and start it on the 8888 port.

Comment: I tried your package/set up and still got the 'address in use' error. I've updated my question with full code and link to the package.

Comment: @Karric - OK, now with more complete code, I've rewritten my answer.  You were trying to create two servers on the same port.  Obviously, can't do that and the 'address in use' error is what you get when you attempt to do that.

Comment: Thanks for the help, I assumed express had to listen as well, but I should have known better.